# Vagrant Puppet guest cli output on host

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I have been using Vagrant with Puppet for a few days; this is a cool tool in the context of automation.

I have a question. Sometimes `apt` operations (or `git clone`) take a few minutes to download all the packages. Vagrant logs all operations on the host's cli, but only those that have already been performed. There is no information about the currently executing task, so I am not sure if the machine hanged or if an operation is still running.

Is there a possibility to output all the guest's cli output on the host's cli in Vagrant?

I am running Vagrant 1.4.3 on Windows 8 via Git Bash and this solution didn't work for me:
[Vagrant provision live output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944855/vagrant-provision-live-output)

Comment: This is not related to Vagrant at all. I don't think you can get the output of the commands from Puppet. If you want to ascertain that the machine is not hung, drop into the VM from a parallel terminal using `vagrant ssh` and use the usual Unix tools to check for running processes, load average, etc (`ps`, `top`, the lot).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass extra options to the puppet command in the `Vagrantfile`, among which `--verbose` and/or `--debug`. This is the example reported in Vagrant documentation ([link](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/puppet_apply.html)):

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
    puppet.options = "--verbose --debug"
  end
end
```

By passing these options the output in the host console should be much more verbose.

Comment: Emyl, thank you for interesting. I have tried this option from documentation before asking. Of course there is more information (about dependencie, performing tasks), but the output from guest tty is not printed out in host console. You can try it itself :)